# Mysql count if the value less or greater than other value

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT wilayah,nilai,t_rkpd,tahun,periode
FROM nilai_indikator
INNER JOIN provinsi ON nilai_indikator.wilayah=provinsi.id
WHERE tahun='2022' AND periode='08' AND id_indikator='6'
```

When i query that code the result is like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh7ks.png)
I try count if the `nilai` is less or greater than `t_rkpd`, using this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN nilai > t_rkpd THEN 1 END) AS tercapai 
FROM nilai_indikator
INNER JOIN provinsi ON nilai_indikator.wilayah=provinsi.id
WHERE tahun='2022' AND periode='08' AND id_indikator='6'

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN nilai < t_rkpd THEN 1 END) AS tidak_tercapai
FROM nilai_indikator
INNER JOIN provinsi ON nilai_indikator.wilayah=provinsi.id
WHERE tahun='2022' AND periode='08' AND id_indikator='6'
```

But the result both of them is 0, it should be 34 when `nilai` greater then `t_rkpd`. why this is happening?

Comment: You can't compare a number with `NULL`, use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values by a number. So instead of checking for example `nilai > t_rkpd`, check something like `COALESCE(nilai,0) > COALESCE(t_rkpd,0)` or exclude `NULL values` in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include both sample table data _and the expected result_  - both as properly formatted text (i.e. no images, no links.)

Comment: Yep, there just is no row where nilai is known to be greater or less than t_rkpd, as t_rkpd is null,  i.e. unknown. So, the counts of zero are correct.

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN nilai > t_rkpd THEN 1 END)` == `SUM(nilai > t_rkpd)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the same code using SUM instead of Count and let me know if it works.

```
SELECT ...,SUM(CASE WHEN nilai > t_rkpd THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tercapai 
FROM nilai_indikator
INNER JOIN provinsi ON nilai_indikator.wilayah=provinsi.id
WHERE tahun='2022' AND periode='08' AND id_indikator='6'
GROUP BY ...
```

And you need to group by some column as there is an aggregate. Do let me know if this helps

Comment: That's not the correct idea, have a look at the comments below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that NULL means 0. You just need to add a condition..

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t_rkpd IS NULL OR nilai > t_rkpd  THEN 1 END) AS tercapai 
FROM nilai_indikator
INNER JOIN provinsi ON nilai_indikator.wilayah=provinsi.id
WHERE tahun='2022' AND periode='08' AND id_indikator='6'
```

Comment: Why do you think `COUNT` is more ineffective than `SUM`? You write "I guess". Why not try out rather than guessing?

Comment: I guessed that count might be returning count for all the rows. I just verified, in this case both SUM and COUNT are returning same results.

Answer (score 0):

NULL means "unknown value". So, if you compare nilai with t_rkpd and one of the values is NULL then the answer is "unknown".

You have `COUNT(CASE WHEN nilai > t_rkpd THEN 1 END)`. The `THEN` part gets executed when the expression `nilai > t_rkpd` is true. There is no `ELSE` in the expression, so the DBMS defaults to `ELSE NULL`. This part gets executed when `nilai > t_rkpd` is not true, namely false or unknown.

This means, when nilai or t_rkpd are null, you get a null as an expression result, and `COUNT` ignores this row hence.

In the following query we consider all rows and all comparison results:

```
SELECT result, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN ni.nilai > p.t_rkpd THEN 'nilai > t_rkpd'
      WHEN ni.nilai < p.t_rkpd THEN 'nilai < t_rkpd'
      WHEN ni.nilai = p.t_rkpd THEN 'nilai = t_rkpd'
      ELSE 'unknown'
    END as result
  FROM nilai_indikator ni
  INNER JOIN provinsi p ON ni.wilayah = p.id
  WHERE ni.tahun = 2022
  AND ni.periode = 8 
  AND ni.id_indikator = 6
) compared
GROUP BY result
ORDER BY result;
```